# Titanium: Text area border not showing

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

So I'm creating a text area on a blue background.
I'd like it to have a white border, but blue background, like so:

[image: Mockup of how it's supposed to look]

However, it actually looks like this:

[image: Screenshot from actual app]

The code is:

```
var svSearch = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    color:'white',
    value:'Пребарај по категорија, албум',
    height:35,
    backgroundColor:'#00A0FF',
    top:35,
    left:40,
    width:260,
    font:{
        fontFamily:'Roboto Light',
        fontWeight:'normal',
        fontSize:12
    },
    borderRadius:3,
    borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
    keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBERS_PUNCTUATION,
    returnKeyType:Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED    
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: works fine for me on Android with 3.4.0.GA / Alloy 1.5.0 except maybe border radius should be 10. What versions are you using?

Comment: Looking at it on a live Samsung S3 device, Cyanogen 4.3.1

Comment: Titanium Studio, build: 3.3.0.201407100905

Comment: Not sure how i see the Alloy version

Comment: Installing updates now.

Comment: No, still the same... Trying to get it to work in emulator, but i'm getting an error on that. Will keep you posted.

Comment: tested mine on Genymotion with Android 4.2.2...I would be surprised if Cyanogen made the difference but yeah it would be good to rule it out at least.

Comment: Reluctant to install Genymotion on a machine that already has Parallels on it... One VM is enough :)

Comment: Managed to get it running in 4.0.3 emulator.

Comment: You are right, it could use a 10 radius. It works... Wonder what's up with Cyanogen?